# Installing cloudera Hadoop without internet connection

Tags: hadoop, centos, cloudera

Actually I am trying to install cloudera hadoop cluster with few VMs with CentOS but this  project is under secure environment where I can't use internet.I tried with various tutorial but each and every tutorial needed internet connection at some point of time. Few things I have downloaded instead of `wget` command.But still I couldn't make it.

Can any once share with me how can I do that either using cloudera Manager or manually (without need of any internet connection)??

Comment: you can do that with local repository setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by selecting the path B Manual installation of cloudera specified [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_install_path_b.html) which provide you the option of downloading the parcels online or specifying them from local repository.

OR

You can install the packages individually by using the path C for installation which is explained [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_install_path_c.html#cmig_topic_6_7) on cloudera documentation.